# Windows 10 - Windows firewall keeps being disabled every reboot and after some minutes

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-firewall, cortana

Before reading, some background related to the origin of the problem:

Many persons told me to avoid the anniversary update, as it created many problems to pretty much everyone I'm talking to. I delayed the update but, unluckily (or luckily), the OS did update today regardless the delay setting.

It took about 2 hours to apply the full update, and I'm now experiencing a set of problems, but I think that the origin of each of them is windows firewall related:

Whenever I login in my account, the firewall service is permanently **disabled**.

If I go to services -> windows firewall -> set to Automatic -> Apply -> Start -> OK the firewall works for about half an hour, then it shuts down again.

If I'm lucky enough to have it to last for more than an hour, whenever I reboot the firewall service is still set to disabled.

I don't even want to have the firewall turned on, if it wasn't, however, that since the Anniversary update if my firewall is off I experience the following problems:

- Cortana sometimes doesn't work.
- Windows store applications won't start.
- Automatic updates won't run anymore (which is not a great deal).
- Sometimes windows store applications re-register themselves automatically.

I've tried to follow multiple fixes found online (including microsoft fixes) but nothing worked.

Possibly important informations:
I'm running a windows 10 professional upgraded from Windows 7 professional, and never had such issues with the firewall before windows update.
Antivirus: AVG professional

Any hint / clue on how to solve the firewall problem at first?

Thanks.

Comment: Is AVG somehow causing the Windows firewall to shutdown?  I presume it has its own so may be overriding it.  As for the Anniversary update, you can uninstall it within 10 days of it being installed.

Comment: @Stephen: even by permanently shutting down AVG the firewall stills gets disabled. Moreover, AVG is only covering the antivirus purpose, it has not the firewall module activated (nor purchased). If I get back to the previous update, however, it probably will still try to someday re-apply the update though (like it did now), so I was wondering whether there was a cleverer solution.

Comment: Not sure about a clever solution but if you uninstall the Anniversary update  and it stops, you know it's the update.  There's been a number of issues with the AU which Microsoft are looking at so I presume future patches will fix any errors that have been discovered.

Comment: @Stephen Ok thanks, I will revert to the previous update and update the question :)

Comment: @Stephen Reverting to the previous-update version seems to have fixed the issue, hence I think I will not update until I'm forced to. Thanks for the tip :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of investigations, it comes out it was a network firewall installed on the DHCP server which was interfering with the server's Windows firewall which was, because of the network policies, interfering with every machine's firewall.

Comment: To clarify, is this machine working within a corporate and/or a domain environment?

Comment: @Run5k : Yes, it is in a domain environment. I was unable to guess the issue because we hadn't full control on the server, hence we were unable to understand where the problematic was. After formatting the machine multiple times and noticing that the issue was only happening once the machine was being put in the domain, we guessed that the issue was probably server related (and it was, as expected). In a nutshell: windows firewall was (of course) not the issue, though it was very hard to guess what the problematic could exactly be.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but this may serve as a rather valuable "lesson learned" regarding the need to be very thorough with the details you include when you originally post your question.  For example, I manage several Windows domains.  If you had told us back in October 2016 that this machine belonged to a domain, we probably could have helped you reduce those *"months of investigations"* down to merely **hours** of troubleshooting, instead.  It makes a big difference.

Comment: @Run5k : You're right, I wouldn't even say that I didn't think that it could've been a "relevant" point, I just had excluded such because other machines in the same domain had no issues, while this one had (which kind of lead me to believe that the issue should've been related to that machine specifically).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but within the Super User realm it is better to provide too much pertinent information, rather than not enough.  As I said before, we are always glad to help.  However, when you author a new question and ask the volunteers for their expertise, it is unwise to assume that some factor is **not** a potential root cause of the problem.  You need to ensure that people who are helping you troubleshoot the issue are starting from scratch, rather that eliminating important facts.  If I had known the whole story, I probably could have helped you solve it the same day.